# C# Create system functions on a dll

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm starting a new C# project and I was wondering how to create functions inside a dll to interact with the app environment, for example, a function that returns the executable path or a function to set full screen mode for the app.

I've tried this but I don't know how to call the code inside the functions:

```
public class StdMethods
{       

    public string GetExePath()
    {
        return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;            
    }

    public void SetFullScreenMode()
    {
        this.Top = 0;
        this.Left = 0;
        this.Width = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
        this.Height = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
    }

}
```

I've tried using System.Windows.Window and pass a Window window argument to the second function but it doesn't work, any ideas and recommendations for the future to use this kind of functions in my next projects? 
Thank you so much.

Comment: What error do you get and where?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but I think that's because you don't understand what you're asking. Do you know how a .dll works? Do you know how to reference it in another project?

Answer (score 3):

Whatever is `public` in what you call `dll` (and what is normally named "class library project" in Visual Studio) is indeed visible for it consumers. So in your case `public class HelpfulMethodsHolder {}` will work.

Side note. Don't do it. `public class HelpfulMethodsHolder {}` will probably look and feel like a totally wrong design. Think twice before mess up your architecture.

Comment: In this situation and suggested usage, shouldn't your "HelpfulMethodsHolder" be static? That's a rhetorical question.

Comment: @Krythic, well.. nope. In most cases singletons (aka static classes) are examples of poor design. And when I say "most cases", I mean nearly 99% of what I've seen so far - both open source and not. And by saying all this, I assume we're not considering pure functional languages.

Comment: So your would be keen on creating an instance of HelpfulMethodsHolder every time you needed it? How is that a better design than HelpfulMethodsHolder.SetFullScreen(Window window)? Consider C# static Math class. In your mind it would be better to create a Math math = new Math(); math.Floor(value)?

Comment: Nope. You would probably create an `interface IHelpflMethodsHolder` and define there your signatures. Then and only then you might do `static HelfulMethodsHolderFactory` with a **single** method: `IHelpflMethodsHolder CreateNew()`. Thus you would achieve proper testability and avoid `new` keyword duplication all over the code. But even such a solution holds the main problem I've mentioned above: **existence of such a class most likely indicates poor-poor-poor design**.

Comment: And once again, `.NET` with it's "standard libraries" IS DEFINITELY NOT an example of good code. And it tends to get **much worse** when you deal with something like WPF.

Answer (score 2):

You can make static class & method like below.

```
public static class StdMethods
{
   public static string GetExePath()
    {
        return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;            
    }

public static void SetFullScreenMode()
    {
      this.Top = 0;
      this.Left = 0;
      this.Width = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
      this.Height = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
    }

}
```

and use it like
`StdMethods.SetFullScreenMode();`